# mongoose, how to create a schema has object in it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here's my photoSchema. it has a dbEntry object.  should I create another dbEntry schema and ref it in the photoSchema. Or whatever I have is good enough? I am new to mongodb, try to figure out a correct way to create schema.

```
    var photoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userId:         ObjectId,
        type:           String,
        createdOn:      {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        isDeleted:      {type: Boolean, default: false},
        isDownloaded:   {type: Boolean, default: false},

        dbFile: String,
        dbEntry: {
            revision:       Number,
            rev:            String,
            thumb_exists:   Boolean,
            bytes:          Number,
            modified:       Date,
            client_mtime:   Date,
            path:           { type: String, unique: true}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to access the data. If you want to get the dbEntry object each time you query a photoSchema document, then what you have is probably the way to go.

If however, you're going to use dbEntry independent of the photoSchema document, then you should split it up and just keep a ref to it.

You can always fetch the ref using mongoose "populate"

Comment: i probably gonna keep whatever I have. cuz, i want to get dbentry object each time I query  photoSchema.  using populat just adds another extra query.